# Fixed bootstrap navbar does not scale on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started debugging my ASP.NET website on my android and noticed that the fixed navbar does not grow/shrink when I zoom in/out. Instead it always shows the top-left of the navbar and the navbar stays the same size.

If I switch to static navbar then it scales perfectly when I zoom in/out. Is this a known problem or have I missed something/done something wrong?

Is there maybe a way to make the navbar static on cellphone only? and fixed on desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question so I have to post this as an answer.

Have you tried using media queries that change the height of the the navbar? Have in mind that you might need to use additional media queries for the items in the navbar, e.g. input, buttons, text size etc.

```
@media screen and (max-width: your-desired-width-in-px) {
    #id-of-the-navbar {
        height: desired-value-in-em/px/%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help! the thing is the navbar acts like its not part of my site almost, when I zoom in/out it just stays the same. And this only happens when it is fixed, not static.

Comment: Can you show me the html and css of the navbar only?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see this till now. The CSS is just standard bootstrap. Ill upload the html tomorrow when I have time  :)

Answer (score -1):

One quick way of doing that could be to use media queries

Comment: sorry, it's because i've got low rep so it wouldn't let me comment is all